# How to intersect a 3D object in THREE.js given an (X, Y) coordinate?

Tags: three.js

I understand that you can intersect a model given unprojected (X, Y) coordinates (e.g. from a mouse) using the RayCaster (i.e. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster). However, I have points within the scene in (X, Y) that I'd like to know whether they intersect a given object and what the updated (X, Y, Z) coordinate would be.

Comment: Do you want track mouse point on plane surface ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that even though all of the examples use the `.setFromCamera` method, there is the `.set` method where you can define an origin and a direction for the Raycaster. This method is here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster.set